# every path in $X$ is homotopic with endpoints fixed to a path passing through $b$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$X$ is path connected and b$\in$X, show every path in $X$ is homotopic with endpoints fixed to a path passing through $b$

This is the hint in the book: Let $\gamma$ be a path from $x$ to $y$. If $\alpha$ is any path from $x$ to $y$, then the path $\alpha(\alpha^{-1}\gamma)$ passes through $b$, and it's homotopic to $\gamma$ with endpoints fixed.

I don't understand why $\alpha(\alpha^{-1}\gamma)$  has to pass through $b$

Thanks

Comment: Because of a typo. It ought to be "If $\alpha$ is any path from $x$ to $b$".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean from $b$ to $y$

Comment: @Carl No, in the notation I'm used to, the left path is traversed first, so $\alpha(\alpha^{-1}\gamma)$ goes from $x$ to $b$, back to $x$, then to $y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah yeah, if it's traversing left to right then you're right.